# Java - Some Ogg clips won't play

Tags: java, audio

I have a Java game where only 1 of the sound files will play (the theme to the game). All the other sound effects will either work once and then never again, or give me this error: Error reading first page of Ogg bitstream data.

They have the same bitrate, same sample rate, and are all edited by Audacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this one file abnormally larger then the others?  I have noticed issues with using large filed .wav's, maybe the same issue is occurring with your .ogg's.  I'm no audio expert though...

PS: New stackoverflow user here so please let me know if I am doing things wrong!

Comment: Yes, the theme song is almost 2 minutes long, and the others are very short little sound effects.

Comment: I believe what I said above is correct. To make sure that this is indeed the case, try shortening the clip and see if it will play. If it still won't, then it's not the length, but if it does then...well...it is. Good luck!

Comment: Will lengthening the shorter clips help if length is the issue? I'm thinking length is because sometimes the shorter clips will still play.

Comment: Length is the issue. The problem is that these sound effects need to be a short length. Any way I can fix this w/o affecting length?

Comment: Short should not be an issue, long should be.  Do I have things the other way around?